# find records based on a binary data

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have lots of records in a collection. They are indexed with a binary uuid :

```
db.users.find().limit(1);
[{ "_id": ..., "guid": BinData(2,"EAAAANR56IodpE3xhYLtfugc7SY="), otherdata }]
```

If I query from the CLI, I can retrieve the records:

```
db.users.find({ "guid": BinData(2,"EAAAANR56IodpE3xhYLtfugc7SY=") });
[{ "_id": ..., "guid": BinData(2,"EAAAANR56IodpE3xhYLtfugc7SY="), otherdata }]
```

If I want to do the same thing from PHP, the query returns nothing:

```
$client->db->setProfilingLevel(2);
$res = $client->db->users->find(array('guid' => new MongoBinData($bin_data, 2)));
$res->next();  // perform the query

echo $res->count(); // display 0
```

Of course I have tested the `$bin_data` variable hold the right value.

If I look at mongo's logs,

```
Thu Jan 10 18:05:06 [conn1] query db.users query: { guid: BinData } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:14807 nreturned:0 reslen:20 14ms
```

the `scanned` value is 0 ! This means it does not even scan the collection for results ?

Any clue ?

**Edit** I have set the profiling level to 2, it does change anything. I can see authentication in the logs but still no query.

**Edit2** Added log line.

Comment: Hmm you are using the bye array type there but the guid type is actually 3: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongobindata.php, that's not your problem but it was the first thing that came to mind

Comment: As you can see below I tried to run this myself with success, can you tell us what PHP driver version this is? Also can you give us a complete script that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit I am confused myself. I ran:

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->mydb;

$col = $db->gjgjgj->insert(
    array( "guid" => new MongoBinData("EAAAANR56IodpE3xhYLtfugc7SY=", 2) )
);
var_dump($col);

$cur = $db->gjgjgj->find(
    array( "guid" => new MongoBinData("EAAAANR56IodpE3xhYLtfugc7SY=", 2) )
);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($cur));
```

And my output was:

```
boolean true

array
  '50ef0bc96803fa0b04000000' => 
    array
      '_id' => 
        object(MongoId)[7]
          public '$id' => string '50ef0bc96803fa0b04000000' (length=24)
      'guid' => 
        object(MongoBinData)[9]
          public 'bin' => string 'EAAAANR56IodpE3xhYLtfugc7SY=' (length=28)
          public 'type' => int 2
```

Can you tell us what PHP driver version this is?

Can you also post your entire script that can reproduce this?

#### Edit

Of course running `count()` after running a `next()` on the cursor works for me too.

Comment: Your code work as expected. This means the `bin_string` I have provided is not good (I still do not know why). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @greg it could be the originating source, unless you are using this script from the same origin in which case I am confussled

Comment: The first guid I have is extracted by a script from mongo and used as parameter to call the second script. This means there must be an alteration somewhere but I still do not know what has changed and when it is changed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo doesn't log all queries by default. Only slow queries (usually taking more than 100 milliseconds) are logged. Also check out [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) on profiling.

Comment: I was able to grab the query log line after restarting my server. It says I scanned 0 lines in the collection.

Comment: cool. So you got your problem resolved. I am glad if I was able to help :)

Comment: Well ... I don't think it means my query has no result, I think it says it did not parse the collection for results ... so my problem remains :/

Comment: Oh ok... sorry. So on mongo shell, have you checked system.profile collection. What do u get there after setting profiler to 2. You said with php you are having appropriate values being hold in variables. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongoDB profiling from php to see what is happining there

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setprofilinglevel.php

```
$this->command(array('profile' => 2))
```

Comment: I have added the `$db->setProfilingLevel(2)` but still do not have the query in the logs. I am going to change this setting at server level.

Comment: I have tried `$db->command(array('query' => array('show' => 'profile')))` with no success.